# Rename files with unreadable filenames in bulk

Tags: rename, bulk

I've downloaded a few RAR files with a bunch of PDF files. Unfortunately, all the names of these files are in Russian. I can extract the RAR files perfectly, but then I end up with a lot of files which show question marks in Explorer instead of the original characters.

With Explorer (or other Windows tools) I cannot open or access these files. However, Total Commander or other shells allow me to access, open, or rename these files. The problem is that I would need to do this for each and every directory and file, which is very cumbersome.

Is there a tool that renames files and directories in bulk? I don't care what the result names are, as long as I can access the files to sort through them manually.

Other workarounds are, of course, more than welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is>>>>https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

Comment: Interesting choice, @Moab. Even the Main Screen is looking scary.

Comment: Easier than it looks, and more flexible than other software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of installing other Static Software Applications, you can use just the one that you have already mentioned: GHISLER_Christian's "*Total Commander*" File-Management Software Utility.

Just select the Files that you want to rename:

[image: Selecting Files]

Then press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> Key Combination.

[image: Multi-Rename Tool]

You have to play with a kind of Regular Expressions that are described in the User Manual.

Comment: I didn't know about this key combination (d'oh!), it's exactly what I'm looking for... Thank you very much!

Comment: We feel that there is no need for you to slap your own forehead, @DeeKay, and to utter those strange sounds like "_d'oh_" in relation to the discovery of the Multi-Rename Tool. We have been using it ourselves a few times and it is quite intricate. Frankly, the last time we remember, we have preferred to manually rename ten to fifteen Files instead of using it. Take care reading carefully the User Manual and learning the Regular Expressions that it is teaching you. In time, it might prove to be a very powerful Software Utility.